# Why is the new Thresh Blood Moon skin unavailable?

Tags: league-of-legends

I thought the new Thresh skin was released, and it's showing up in the list of possible skins to choose from, but when I click "buy skin" it says it is unavailable.

If it's brand new, and unavailable when/how was it ever available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They sometimes add new skins to the store as "unavailable" when they are to be released this patch but only in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't released yet, it's only on show at the moment. It should be enabled and put on sale within a few weeks or next patch tops.